# run php file from jquery conditionally

Tags: php, jquery, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I have a mysql table "users" that has user info including the balance they pledge to donate. I want to have a div that when clicked adds 10 to their balance and refreshes the balance which is displayed below.
I have the following for the page.Let me know what can i add in php call section..

```
<script>
function showPopup(task) {
    var form = document.getElementById(\'popupForm\');
    var ppd = document.getElementById(\'popupDivBack_ara\');
    var ppd2 = document.getElementById(\'popupDiv_ara\');
    if ('.count($templates).' == 1) {
        form.task.value = task;
        form.templateID.value =\''.$template.
        '\';
        form.submit();
    } else if (form != null && ppd != null && ppd2 != null) {
        //$.get("update.php"); CALL PHP FILE HERE

        ppd.style.display =\'block\';
        ppd2.style.display =\'block\';
        form.task.value = task;
    } else {
        alert(\'Error!\');
    }
}
</script>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place php vars inside double quotes, not single quotes. In php file you need to connect to a database and perform an insert query for your table.

Comment: php is individually working well but im not sure where here the update.php is been called...

Comment: You can add an action attribute to your form's html. <form action="update.php">

Comment: <?php
    global $current_user;
        $u_id=$current_user->id;
       $no_done=$current_user->used_prints_c;
        $no_done=$no_done+1;
        $sql = "UPDATE `users_cstm` SET `used_prints_c`='".$no_done."' WHERE `id_c`= '".$u_id."'";
        $res = $this->bean->db->query($sql);

Comment: im trying to execute this in update.php and when the same code is implemented in same php file its getting executed i need the condition like if there are forms then need to execute this php script thanks

Comment: this script is in php file which im trying to echo the script but on selected the option based on jquery i need to execute sql query

Comment: You want to make sure that php file is executed with all parameters from form?

Comment: yeah thanks the script is in echo is it possible?? to run ajax in echo php

Comment: Yes it is. But the script and form action file should be different files.